# Activating Mobile Hotspot in Win10 does disable the internet connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-hotspot

I have the following problem:
On my Win10 Laptop I use a WiFi connection to the university network to get internet access in my dorm room. I use a WiFi dongle with a USB-extension cable because I only get a good signal at the window. In order to get a WiFi for other devices in the dorm room I want to use the Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot feature. But whenever I activate it, my internet connection (which was working perfectly before) is not working anymore and I cannot even ping the google DNS server (4.4.4.4 or 8.8.8.8). The original WiFi connection (to the university network) is still listed as connected though. Could not find this phenomenon on google so I am asking here. Does anybody have an idea what the reason for this could be?

Fun fact: The concept was already working some months ago, for like 3 weeks but no success since then. Dunno what changed, maybe Windows Update?

Update:
This seems to be some sort of Heisenbug. For some reason if I enable the Mobile Hotspot now, the internet on my laptop keeps working. However, the clients are not connecting to the Mobile Hotspot saying they did not get an IP. So, basically, the originally posted problem is not anymore. I have no clue why that part at least is working again. Windows Update? ^^

Comment: It was working with the same wireless adapter?

Comment: What are your WiFi adapter and current driver?  Try : (1) Running Troubleshooting / Network Adapter. (2) In Device Manager right-click the wireless adapter and choose Properties / Driver tab / Roll Back Driver (report if button is available). (3) Still in Device Manager right-click the wireless adapter and delete the device then reboot to reinstall it.

Comment: Try the `tracert 8.8.8.8` AND `ipconfig -a` commands for starters (with the mobile hotspot enabled ofc) and post it's results here.

Comment: (4)  In PC Settings, click on Network & Internet, and under Network Status click on Network reset on the bottom, then Reset now. (5) Disable firewall and antivirus.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it was working with the same wireless adapter.

Comment: @T_D: Please comment on the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

- In "Network Connections", disable internet sharing
- Delete registry key HostedNetworkSettings in:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings\

(the key name is the same as folder name - be careful)

- Reboot

Try to enable the hotspot again.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Delete the parameters for the hotspot. This will force the registry entries to be recreated like new upon the next enable.